# Aportion blame for this unsolved cryptic crossword clue

Tags: cryptic-clues

I just rediscovered this cryptic crossword clue I transcribed many years ago (from The Guardian or possibly The Times) but, although I keep coming back to it occasionally, I still can't solve it:

> Always a portion more than required (3,4,7)

Notes:

- I don't know the correct answer.
- I (probably) can't verify the 'true' answer but, this being a cryptic crossword clue, I have high hopes of the most likely candidate answer emerging.
- I may have unknowingly transcribed it incorrectly e.g. I can't help wondering whether it should rather be `(4,3,7)`.

Comment: Something is not quite right with the title. I would edit it but I have no idea what you were going for, as "A portion blame for this unsolved cryptic crossword clue" doesn't make sense to me. Was it meant to be "A portion of blame for..." maybe?

Comment: @SpiritFryer: wanted to avoid "Another crossword clue" variant so after 10 seconds of thought decided on a (bad) pun using words from the clue!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it's

> For good measure

Always a portion

> for good = always; measure = a portion

more than required

> this would be the straight

Answer (score 1):

Could it have been "Always a portion more than required (2,4,7)"

> Always more than a portion would be "A Baker's Dozen", the extra being potions always being the "inbread".

= seven characters

> inbread

= first two characters

> in

= last four characters

> read

*MATH

> 2 + 4 + 7 = 13 (a baker's dozen)

I would think the answer would have to fit in a crossword.

https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2014/sep/12/how-to-solve-cryptic-crossword-clues

Comment: I don't see an answer in this post.

Comment: The answer is a word to a crossword puzzle, or could have been a solutions for 3 words. The word 7 characters in length would be the answer. Hard to tell for sure without the puzzle.